# SAP Smart Style character attributes getting overruled with inheritance

Tags: sap-smart-forms

It's a **SAP Smart Form** / **Smart Style** problem.

A Character style "N 12P" was defined in the Smart Style as a normal font and not a bold. This Smart Style was used in the from.

Inside the form settings, for a Label field,  `N 12P`  was selected as its "Character Format" from the drop down list. The "paragraph format" is standard "left aligned".

However, this label field, in place of  "normal" display, is becoming "bold"!
Therefore, even if in the smartstyle, the format `N 12P`, was defined as a normal character, somehow its attributes are getting changed (turning it into a bold character).

Further digging down the character attributes window for that label (General Attributes window → Edit → Formats (glass icon) → double-click format `N P12` → opens the Character attributes window), the Bold field was found marked with  a `*`. On clicking the <kbd>*</kbd>, the "Font attribute bold Type" window displays "inherited".

So, somewhere the Smart Style's character attribute is changing from "normal" to "bold", and this change is somehow being inherited. What possibly could have gone wrong? Is it possible to override the Smart Style's format attribute from within a smartform?

Please note that changing the Smart Style sheet is not possible. But anyways the format defined there is OK i.e. as normal. Therefore, no change is required in the Smart Style.

Comment: It will be hard to identify the issue without actual access to the forms and styles.

Comment: Is it possible to override the smartstyles format attributes from within a smartform?

Comment: "NP12" is not bold in stylesheet but using that style in smartform it is showing BOLD   How is it changing?

Comment: "Working as designed", I'd say....

Answer (score 0):

The assumption had worked. The text editor at the field level was overriding paragraph and character style settings.  It worked after resetting these from within the editor. Thanks

Comment: Could you accept this answer to let others know that this issue is resolved?